# angular-sails websocket url undefined ( ws://www.undefined)

Tags: angularjs, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I am using sails 0.10.5 and in angular frontend with angular-sails .

It gives an error like below on server side Whenever an api call by $sails.get

In My FrontEnd side controller code :

```
 io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';

        io.socket.get('http://localhost:1337/admin/v1/user/subscribe', function (body, response) {
            console.log('Sails responded with: ', body);
            console.log('with headers: ', response.headers);
            console.log('and with status code: ', response.statusCode);
        });
```

and console is

```
 Sails responded with:  Object {}
app.js:167 with headers:  Object {}
app.js:168 and with status code:  200
```

But in backend side sails console gives error like this

```
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Fri Dec 19 2014 10:44:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
error: Error: 
res.redirect() :: [socket.io] ::
Cannot redirect socket to invalid location :: 'ws://www.undefinedhttp://localhost:1337/admin/v1/user/subscribe'
    at Object.Err.invalidRedirect (C:\wamp\www\i-phone\i-phone\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\sockets\lib\interpreter\interpret.js:33:14)
    at ResStream.doRedirect (C:\wamp\www\i-phone\i-phone\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\sockets\lib\interpreter\interpret.js:310:31)
    at C:\wamp\www\i-phone\i-phone\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\sockets\lib\interpreter\saveSessionAndThen.js:23:7
    at C:\wamp\www\i-phone\i-phone\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\session\index.js:59:17
```

My route file is like this :

```
'get    /admin/v1/user/subscribe': 'UserController.subscribe',
```

And in UserController.js :

```
subscribe: function (req, res) {

        console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')

        User.find().exec(function(err,users){

            // subscribing this socket to User model classroom
            User.subscribe(req.socket);

            // subscribing this socket to User model instance room
            User.subscribe(req.socket,users);

            console.log('subscribe')
        })


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was little silly mistake.

In my route.js , I am redirecting non WWW request to WWW request .

And socket request start with ws:// tag , thats why it is being also redirect to www.undefined

It is solved by a small condition

```
if(!req.isSocket){

  // redirect logic
}else{
  next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For setting up Socket connection with server:

Include `sails.io.js` in index.html.
Create a global variable for io.sails.url and you'll need to tell the Sails socket client what URL to connect to:

```
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
```

Put this anywhere before you start making socket calls; the library is smart enough to wait until its connected before trying to make the calls.

To Check if Socket is connected,

```
io.socket.get('http://localhost:1337/data', function (body, response) {
    console.log('Sails responded with: ', body);
    console.log('with headers: ', sailsResponseObject.headers);
    console.log('and with status code: ', sailsResponseObject.statusCode);
});
```

You should be able to see in the console whether or not the socket connected by looking for the `"io.socket connected successfully."` message.

The above code was about setting up socket connection as you requested.
Regarding your problem, Can you please provide some `Code`

Comment: I did all the thing as you suggested, but still not working, I have updated my question now you can see ...

Answer (score 1):

The controller action you posted is clearly not being run (you would see the `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` log in your console).  Some other code is running and is calling `res.redirect` with invalid arguments.  My first guess would be that you have a policy configured in `config/policies.js` that is attached to the `UserController.subscribe` action.